# Getting this error 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk' when passing queryset instance in Serializer with many=True

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a view that is responsible for bulk updating objects, since DRF doesn't provide any generic view for that I proceed with this approach.

In docs they are passing `many=True` and a `queryset` of objects in the serializer.

this is from docs

```
queryset = Book.objects.all()
serializer = BookSerializer(queryset, many=True)
serializer.data
# [
#     {'id': 0, 'title': 'The electric kool-aid acid test', 'author': 'Tom Wolfe'},
#     {'id': 1, 'title': 'If this is a man', 'author': 'Primo Levi'},
#     {'id': 2, 'title': 'The wind-up bird chronicle', 'author': 'Haruki Murakami'}
# ]
```

So decided to do something like that, here is my view.py file

```
class PostListBulkUpdateApiView(GenericAPIView):

    serializer_class = PostListUpdateSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated,
                          HasPostChangePermission,
                          HasPostReadPermission,
                          HasObjectDeletePermission]

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(kwargs.get('data', {}), list):
            kwargs['many'] = True
        return super().get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_queryset(self, ids=None):
        if ids:
            return Post.objects.filter(id__in=ids)
        return Post.objects.all()

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request)

    def patch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.update(request)

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        ids = set()
        for data in request.data:
            id = data.get('id', None)
            if id is not None:
                ids.add(id)
        instance = self.get_queryset(ids=ids)
        serializer = PostListUpdateSerializer(instance=instance,
                                              data=request.data, partial=True, many=True)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

but it give me `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk'` error when performing a `PUT` or `PATCH` request

here is my serializer

```
class PostListUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ['id']

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        ...
```

model.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
    body = models.JSONField(blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

full traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: PATCH
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v2/posts/update

Django Version: 3.2.7
Python Version: 3.8.10
Installed Applications:
['whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.forms',
 'rest_framework',
 'rest_framework_simplejwt',
 'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
 'django_filters',
 'blog',
 'blog_media',
 'category',
 'comment',
 'contact',
 'user',
 'core_api',
 'mptt',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.github',
 'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
 'django_social_share',
 'corsheaders',
 'debug_toolbar']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/karunamay/projects/blog_rest_api/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/karunamay/projects/blog_rest_api/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/karunamay/projects/blog_rest_api/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/karunamay/projects/blog_rest_api/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/karunamay/projects/blog_rest_api/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/karunamay/projects/blog_rest_api/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/karunamay/projects/blog_rest_api/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/karunamay/projects/blog_rest_api/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/karunamay/projects/blog_rest_api/blog/views.py", line 240, in patch
    return self.update(request)
  File "/home/karunamay/projects/blog_rest_api/blog/views.py", line 251, in update
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
  File "/home/karunamay/projects/blog_rest_api/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 748, in is_valid
    self._validated_data = self.run_validation(self.initial_data)
  File "/home/karunamay/projects/blog_rest_api/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 618, in run_validation
    value = self.to_internal_value(data)
  File "/home/karunamay/projects/blog_rest_api/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 666, in to_internal_value
    validated = self.child.run_validation(item)
  File "/home/karunamay/projects/blog_rest_api/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 426, in run_validation
    value = self.to_internal_value(data)
  File "/home/karunamay/projects/blog_rest_api/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 483, in to_internal_value
    validated_value = field.run_validation(primitive_value)
  File "/home/karunamay/projects/blog_rest_api/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 751, in run_validation
    return super().run_validation(data)
  File "/home/karunamay/projects/blog_rest_api/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 548, in run_validation
    self.run_validators(value)
  File "/home/karunamay/projects/blog_rest_api/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 560, in run_validators
    validator(value, self)
  File "/home/karunamay/projects/blog_rest_api/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/validators.py", line 72, in __call__
    queryset = self.exclude_current_instance(queryset, instance)
  File "/home/karunamay/projects/blog_rest_api/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/validators.py", line 60, in exclude_current_instance
    return queryset.exclude(pk=instance.pk)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/v2/posts/update
Exception Value: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

Comment: It would be better if you added your model, too. And also, which action triggers this error, creating, updating?

Comment: @JetEzra I have added the model. and only the update action triggering the issue

Comment: Could you please share the full traceback ?

Comment: @Alombaros Yes, I update the question with full traceback

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the line `instance = self.get_queryset(ids=ids)` this returns a queryset not an instance, `instance = self.get_queryset(ids=ids).first()` should do the trick.

You should not need to override `get_queryset` to do what you're trying to do, the `.get_object()` method should be sufficient

I think you're also mixing things up with you're usage of serializers.
With patch and put should call the serializer with the `data=` argument (which you did), then calling `serializer.is_valid()` (which you did) **but** you then need to call `serializer.save()` to apply the changes.
If you want the updated instance in the response body, your code should look something like that:

```
serializer = PostListUpdateSerializer(instance=instance, data=request.data, partial=True)
serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
updated_instance = serializer.save()
serializer = PostListUpdateSerializer(updated_instance)
return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Even if I remove `serializer.save()` it still gives me the error. And I think I do need a `queryset` in instance as I'm also passing `many=True`

Comment: Try to only change `instance = self.get_queryset(ids=ids).first()` as a beginning